# AngularJS + Flask Client-Side Routing

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I have an application with an AngularJS frontend and a Flask backend.

I have the following routes in Flask to send all requests to the index.html file (as well as some routes for API routes):

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api/colours')
def colours():
    ...

@app.route('/<path:page>')
def fallback(page):
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I'm then using the Angular StateProvider for the client-side routing:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/home.html'
    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact', 
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/contact.html'
    });
```

This works great if I start at the root of my website and click a link to take me to the contact page. However, if I want to go to straight to the contact page by typing in `mysite.com/contact` it redirects the homepage. Which is expected.

How can I allow it go to the client side route if it's available, else redirect to home page?

Comment: What do you mean by "Which is expected"? it has to show you contact.html right?

Comment: I meant it's expected because the server-side routing rule says redirect home, as it doesn't know about /contact.

Comment: I see. Right answer is already given in that case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From server side if you encounter home or unknown route (404) you should return `index.html` since you don't know if client side can handle this route. After `index.html` is loaded client side routing should take over and decide whether to redirect to `Not found` or handle this route in some other way.

```
@app.route('/<path:page>')
def fallback(page):
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: That works. Rendering index.html is correct instead of routing to home and rendering index.html from there. Thanks @Žilvinas!

Comment: Also for Angular > 2!

Comment: Yes, this works for Angular 11+.
Now we need to make 404 with Angular.
let's Angular do the job!